# Ionic 4 Migration : What are the Angular equivalent of Ionic 3 lifecycle events/nav guards?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having a tough time doing Ionic 3 to 4 migration. The Official [migration guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration#lifecycle-events) asks us to use "*the proper Angular alternatives*". Can anyone tell me the equivalent [Angular lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#component-lifecycle-hooks-overview) replacements for the following [Ionic 3 lifecycle-hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/).

1. ionViewDidLoad
2. ionViewWillEnter [not replaced]
3. ionViewDidEnter [not replaced]
4. ionViewWillLeave [not replaced]
5. ionViewDidLeave [not replaced]
6. ionViewWillUnload
7. ionViewCanEnter
8. ionViewCanLeave

Please help me match the above with

1. ngOnChanges()
2. ngOnInit()
3. ngDoCheck()
4. ngAfterContentInit()
5. ngAfterContentChecked()
6. ngAfterViewInit()
7. ngAfterViewChecked()
8. ngOnDestroy()

Edit :  I have indeed gone through [Ionic 4 router-outlet](http://%20%20%20https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet) docs.

Comment: Added the list below

Answer (score 4):

ionViewDidLoad => ngOnInit()

ionViewWillUnload => ngOnDestroy()

From [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) :

> ngOnInit()
>   Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.
>
> ngOnDestroy()
>
> Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

For ionViewCanEnter() and ionViewCanLeave() you have to use [Router Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) as suggested in the docs.
For eg. If you want to guard a route against an unauthenticated user you have to first create service file to check for authentication

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
}
```

and then in your route path use the service in canActivate property:

```
{path:'home',component:HomeComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
```

Comment: Just stumbled with the same thing, what is equivalent Angular hook for ionViewDidEnter

Answer (score 3):

1. ionViewDidLoad replaced by ngOnInit
2. ionViewWillEnter [not replaced]
3. ionViewDidEnter [not replaced]
4. ionViewWillLeave [not replaced]
5. ionViewDidLeave [not replaced]
6. ionViewWillUnload replaced by ngOnDestroy
7. ionViewCanEnter replaced by CanActivate
8. ionViewCanLeave replaced by CanDeactivate